# Only allow Read file permissions for Default Users group while not overriding the Read & Execute permissions for default Administrators group

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I'm trying to prevent standard users from being able to execute a specific .exe file while still allowing administrators to execute it.

If I edit the file's security settings to Deny Read & Execute for the Default Users group, this prevents users in BOTH the default users group AND the administrators group from executing the file. This was expected because it's my understanding that Deny rules override Allow rules for users with conflicting rule sets.

From what I read I'm under the impression that instead of explicitly denying the Default Users Group from being able to Read & Execute that I could simply not Allow Default Users Group to be able to Read & Execute. However, this seems to have the same effect as explicitly denying the privilege. Is this how it's supposed to work?

The only way I know how to deny standard users while allowing admin users to read & execute a particular .exe file is to create a new group for standard users and to deny that new group that permission. This is easy enough to do for one or two computers but I have multiple computers this needs to be done to so am looking for a simpler solution that will require less steps.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

If it's critical that random users should not execute the file, then denying *execute* for the file would be insufficient, because there would be nothing to stop a user from *copying* the file and executing it elsewhere.

Instead, use [Group Policy](https://www.lepide.com/blog/what-is-group-policy-gpo-and-what-role-does-it-play-in-data-security/) to block execution of each specific application: `User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Don't run specified Windows applications`. You could also use the next setting, `Run only specified Windows applications` for blanket rsetrictions.

[image: GPO App Permissions]